# ¿Cómo puedo activar ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown solo en debug?

Tags: delphi, fastmm

Necesito activar la funcionalidad `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` para reportar las fugas de memoria de mi aplicación, pero quiero hacerlo solamente en modo *debug*, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
project MiProyecto;
uses FastMM;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  ....
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se considera *modo debug* a las aplicaciones compiladas utilizando la configuración *debug build* en Delphi 2007 o superior. En estos casos, si has dejado la configuración como viene de fábrica, tendrás definido el símbolo `DEBUG`, así que puedes activar `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` solamente en ese caso, independientemente de si el programa es lanzado desde dentro del IDE o no.

Adapta el código para que luzca así:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
{$ENDIF}
```

Por otro lado, si quieres ejecutarlo únicamente si se lanzó la ejecución desde dentro del IDE y hay un *debugger* presente, puedes utilizar la variable [`DebugHook`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.DebugHook), de la siguiente manera:

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;
```